# Assigning closure to struct variable in initialiser

Tags: swift, struct, closures

I have a Swift struct where two of the member variables are closures:

```
struct SettingsItem {
    var title: String = ""
    var textColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    var selected: () -> Bool = { return false }
    var action: () -> Void = { }
}
```

When I try to create an instance of this struct, I get an error `User of unresolved identifier 'selected'`. Example:

```
var settingsItem = SettingsItem(title: "Title", selected = { return true }, action = {})
```

When I assign the variables separately, it works:

```
var settingsItem = SettingsItem()
settingsItem.title = ""
settingsItem.selected = { return true }
```

How can I resolve this error? I am creating a large array of `SettingsItem`s so it will be much cleaner code if I can use initialisers rather than the more verbose option.

Comment: The first problem is that arguments are passed as `selected: ...`, not `selected = ...`

Comment: And the second problem is that textColor: is missing. Default initializer does not have default values.

Comment: And the other issue is that you rely on default initializer that contains ALL properties. Add textColor, or write your own initializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

- Arguments are passed as `selected: ...`, not `selected = ...`.
- There is only a default memberwise initializer which takes *all*
  properties as arguments.

So this would compile:

```
var settingsItem = SettingsItem(title: "Title",
                              textColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1),
                              selected: { return true },
                              action: {})
```

If you define a custom initializer with default argument values

```
struct SettingsItem {
    let title: String
    let textColor: UIColor
    let selected: () -> Bool
    let action: () -> Void

    init(title: String,
         textColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1),
         selected: @escaping () -> Bool = { return false },
         action: @escaping () -> Void = { })
    {
        self.title = title
        self.textColor = textColor
        self.selected = selected
        self.action = action
    }
}
```

then the corresponding arguments are optional, for example:

```
let settingsItem = SettingsItem(title: "Title", selected: { return true })
```

Comment: These closures are not escaping, so @escaping is not necessary.

Comment: Ahh yes the equals instead of the colon. Sometimes the solution is just so blindingly obvious. Fixing that has shown me the error about missing arguments, so I'll add additional initialisers to account for that.

Comment: @MichaelBernat: They are escaping, and the keyword is necessary (otherwise the compiler complains). Compare https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID546: *"One way that a closure can escape is by being stored in a variable that is defined outside the function.  ..."*

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the notice! (yes, you are right...)

Answer (score 1):

You have define custom init method for struct

try this

```
struct SettingsItem {
    var title: String = ""
    var textColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    var selected: () -> Bool = { return false }
    var action: () -> Void = { }

    init(title: String, textColor: UIColor, selected: @escaping () -> Bool, action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.title = title
        self.textColor = textColor
        self.selected = selected
        self.action = action
    }
}
```

and you can call like this

```
SettingsItem(title: "title", textColor: .red, selected: { () -> Bool in
        code ...
    }) {
        code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing arguments in this way should work for you

```
var settingsItem = SettingsItem(title: "Title", textColor: UIColor.red, selected: { () -> Bool in
    return true
}) {
    return
}
```